# SQL query with unique incrementing id for each group of rows (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `student` with an identifying column `name` of type `TEXT`. I'm looking to have a query that deterministically outputs an incrementing id for each group of unique name. For example:

```
------+----------
 name | group_id
------+----------
  A   |    1
  A   |    1
  B   |    2
  C   |    3
  D   |    4
  D   |    4
  D   |    4
```

I've looked at windowing functions in PSQL (currently running PostgreSQL 13.2) but no luck. Feel like it's a simple thing to do, but can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: looks like ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME DESC)AS GROUP_ID

Comment: Unfortunately, the ROW_NUMBER() function assigns one to first row of each partition and increases for each row in the same partition. What I'm looking for is to assign one to the EVERY row in the first partition, and increase by one for each partition following.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2615fa14b43f085f280868777208f4e4)

That's exactly what [`dense_rank()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) does.

```
SELECT
    *,
    dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY name) as group_id
FROM t
```

Comment: Ah, thankyou! The key I was missing is that you just use the ORDER BY on the column, not the PARTITION BY. I don't fully understand why yet, but at least I know what I'm looking at.